# Cloud composer: "PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission"

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-composer

I implemented a few tasks with BashOperator. Ones with "gsutil rm" and "gsutil cp" worked fine. But one with "gcloud alpha firestore export" generates this error:

```
{bash_operator.py:101} INFO - ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.firestore.export) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

This command itself works fine in gcloud shell. I tried to give some Firestore related permissions to the service account used by the Composer but it still doesn't work. Any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a new service account with the Firestore-related permissions needed and using that on a freshly created environment. https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control

Other debugging ideas: * Try ssh-ing into the Kubernetes workers on your Composer environment and running the command. *Is the Firestore API enabled on your project?

Answer (score 13):

It might be that you don't have permissions for a particular **project**.

The error I was getting was: `PERMISSION_DENIED: Caller does not have required permission to use project project:random-id-11111.`

The way I resolved it was by running `gcloud config set project 'the-right-project-id'` and then the actual `gcloud` command.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need Cloud Datastore Import Export access. Following are the steps as per current Current Google Cloud platform layout.

https://console.cloud.google.com > Left drawer > IAM & admin > Against user - Edit Icon > Add another role > Data Store > Cloud Datastore Import & Export > Save

Answer (score 2):

1. Open https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam
2. Find the service account you're using for the backups
3. Add the **Owner role** to the service account

It's not really intuitive or logic because there are not permissions or roles for Firestore.

Unfortunately it took me way to long to figure it out. I hope it helps others!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import it has more defined permissions for firestore export

Comment: Do not give any service account Owner role ever. You need the `roles/cloudtrace.agent` role. https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/iam#roles

Comment: I think this has changed since 2018. I believe the owner role is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Roy's answer, the issue for me was that `gcloud` was set to a different project.

#### check which project it is set to

`gcloud config list`

#### list which projects you have access to

gcloud projects list

#### set the correct project

gcloud config set project 'foo-project'

Comment: worked for me after setting up the right project where i want to update the composer environment.

Answer (score 1):

Grant firebase admin role to the default service account that your service is using.

Adding Owner role to the service account seems too much privilege for just taking backup.

Answer (score 1):

In IAM & Admin make sure your @appspot.gserviceaccount.com must have access for 3 things:

- Cloud Functions Admin
- Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin
- Storage Admin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your project first where you are owner
gcloud config set project project-id
You can find your project id by clicking on gcloud console it will be there in popup in project-name-somerandomnumbers

Answer (score 0):

I got caught out on this today. The issue was that I had set up my service account correctly in the IAM settings, but hadn't realised an invitation had been sent to that email address which I needed to accept. Worked immediately once I accepted the invite.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't created any firebase project before, go to firebase, try to create any project and... accept terms. It seems that it was problem in my case.

> {
> "error": {
> "code": 403,
> "message": "The caller does not have permission",
> "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
> }
> }